# Authorize.net Integration

Tags: api, authorize.net

I am attempting to integrate Authorize.net into my site. I have set up and activated a test account in their test.authorize.net domain and have obtained and inserted their API key/login for my account into my configurations. I run my script through their API and I get the proper success message that they've received the information. However, every time I log into the test.authorize.net domain and search for the transactions via their Search tab, it always returns with nothing regardless of what parameters I search with. What can cause this?

Answer (score 3):

Look in the **unsettled transactions**. That's where they'll be.

FYI, Authorize.Net developer accounts do not actually process transactions. They only validate that the data you sent over via their API was valid and complete. If it is you will receive an approved response with a fake transaction number, approval, and AVS response code (which is always a match). If your made an invalid API call an error message will be returned alerting you to your error so you can correct it.

If you don't want o call Authorize.Net for support or they give you the run around, you can also get help in their [developer forums](http://community.developer.authorize.net/).

Comment: its true...just the message that successful or error comes up

Answer (score 2):

Authorize.net does not actually log transactions in test mode.

Comment: I've switched it to the live mode, but in their test.authorize.net domain.

Answer (score 1):

You should call their support; they are fantastic.  However, from my experience you typically get a shared account where lots of tests are running and it can be hard to search for your transaction.